# Convert LaTex to R

Tags: r

We have a UI for users to put down LaTex responses. To evaluate those responses, we translate LaTex to R, then run some script similar to the following to compare the response to the correct answer.

```
x = #{random number}
y = #{random number}
abs(x*x*y - x^2*y) < 10^-6
```

It's working fine for those functions mapped well. For example:

```
\frac{x}{y}      => x/y
\left|x\right|   => abs(x)
{\cdot}          => *
```

But I didn't find any match for the following functions/notations:

```
\hat{x}          -- unit vector
\vec{x}          -- vector
\sqrt[3]{x}      -- nth root
```

Any suggestions?

PS:

There is a hat function in R, but I'm not sure if it's the same as the one in LaTex.

Also, \sqrt[3]{x} can be replaced by x^(1/3). Will this be always working? Any performance concern? Someone's saying x^(1/2) is slower than sqrt(x).

Comment: You can define any symbol to be any operation you want. The better question is what was the author's intent when writing `\hat{x}`. Often that's just used to indicate an estimator and is not actually an operation or function. LaTeX is just pretty markup, it doesn't actually have mathematical meaning unless you assign it some.

Comment: `sqrt(x)` is indeed faster. Try: `x <- runif(1e5); microbenchmark::microbenchmark(x^0.5, sqrt(x))`. On my system, I see a a factor of 2+. It makes sense: `sqrt` is a primitive function with one exponent only so it is well-optimized; whereas `^`, though also a primitive function, has to generalize a little to any (feasible) exponent. In your case, your exponent question should always be safe assuming that the exponent is not zero.

Comment: @MrFlick That's a very good point. `\hat{x}` could be an estimator or a unit vector. We don't have any constraint on UI part, so it could mean either of it. This makes it trickier.

Comment: @r2evans thanks for confirming the performance part.